# How to make a directed graph in python?

Tags: graphs, python

I am working on my own personal project. I took an intro to coding class last semester so I have been exposed to coding but I am still lost with it.

Basically, for my project, I want to build a web map (I'm not even sure if that's the right word for it) using python. Here is an example.

[image]

Basically, some numbers will have arrows leading to them and others will have arrows leading out of them. I was wondering if maybe someone knew of any libraries that generated something like this. If not, I was wondering if anyone had any advice on where to start. Or at least can tell me the actual name for this type of graph because I'm not sure if it's actually called a web graph.

Thank you all :)

Comment: There are [directed graphs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) - in `generated something like this`, is *this* the illustration or the graph illustrated?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a *directed graph*. For a Python graph library, you can have a look at networkx. There are other libraries too, like igraph and graph-tool.

Answer (score 1):

There are many resources for creating [Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)).

If you're a visual thinker you can create the networks with visual online tools download the graph in .graphml format and import it to Python.

Here are some sources: [CSacademy](https://csacademy.com/app/graph_editor/), [GraphOnline](https://graphonline.ru/en/)
[image: GraphOnline Example:]

```
# import the modules
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the graph
G = nx.read_graphml("filename.graphml", node_type=str)

# Visualize
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()
```

If you are confident with python you can start with these modules rightaway:
[Networkx](https://networkx.org/), [Igraph](https://igraph.org/python/), [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/)

I would recommend Networkx since there are tons of study materials available online!

Happy coding!

Comment: If your graphs are large and/or performance is critical, networkx is not a great choice though.

Comment: Agreed! For me, NetworkX was a great entry point into the field because of all the tutorials available. I guess since OP seems new to programming he probably won't be dealing with that level of complexity right away.